# Boost serialization. Unexpected exception

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

```
    class OByteStream
    {
    public:
        explicit OByteStream(std::string &s)
                   : _backInsertDevice(s)
                   , _stream(_backInsertDevice)
                   , _oArchive(_stream)
                   {
                   }

        void flush()
                   {
                       _stream.flush();
                   }

        template<class T>
        OByteStream &operator<<(const T &data)
                   {
                       _oArchive << data;
                       return *this;
                   }

    private:
        typedef boost::iostreams::back_insert_device<std::string> BackInsertDevice;
        typedef boost::iostreams::stream<BackInsertDevice> Stream;
        typedef boost::archive::binary_oarchive BinaryOArchive;

        BackInsertDevice _backInsertDevice;
        Stream _stream;
        BinaryOArchive _oArchive;
    };

    class IByteStream
    {
    public:
        explicit IByteStream(const std::string &s)
            : _basicArraySource(s.data(), s.size())
            , _stream(_basicArraySource)
            , _iArchive(_stream)
        {
        }

        template<class T>
        IByteStream &operator>>(T &data)
        {
            _iArchive >> data;
            return *this;
        }

    private:
        typedef boost::iostreams::basic_array_source<char> BasicArraySource;
        typedef boost::iostreams::stream<BasicArraySource> Stream;
        typedef boost::archive::binary_iarchive BinaryIArchive;

        BasicArraySource _basicArraySource;
        Stream _stream;
        BinaryIArchive _iArchive;
    };
```

When I unserialize structure containing two dimensions vectors I get input_stream_error.

```
if(scount != s)
    boost::serialization::throw_exception(
    archive_exception(archive_exception::input_stream_error)
    );
```

How can I fix it?

Or if there are complete realizations of byte streams I'm glad to become acquainted with them.

---

I sent serialized data from application compiled in VS to application compiled in Qt using msvc. This is the reason. How can I fix incorrect unserialization?

I tried to use all Struct Member Alignments in VS. It did not help. In QtCreator I did not find such option.

Comment: Please, show how do you use Boost.Serialization: purpose of you code, actual client code, input, etc.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/rBfNsHU4
  Exceptions throwing when ar & 2d vector (of standard types) but not for all.

Comment: please include your code in-line in the question itself, not as a link to pastebin